# problem CasperJS POST via AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working on a **scraper** of my bank statements with CasperJS, so far I've managed to login and get to the statements page. I accomplished to get the table with the first page of the statement, but I need to get it complete.

The bank's web have the option to export to a .txt file (sort of a CSV actually), but in order to download it I have to be able to download the file that comes as an attachment in the response header of a POST request when I submit a form by clicking a button.

So I figured that I could do the POST via AJAX, get the response and output it. I tried running the code on the firebug console and it works, but for some reason it just doesn't work in CasperJS.

Btw, I have tried using --web-security=no , still doesn't work

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
            this.then(function() {
                eurl = "http://bankurl.com";
                response = this.evaluate(function() {
                params = $("#lForm").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: eurl,
                    data: params,
                    success: function (data) {
                        return data.responseText;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr,status,error){
                        return error;
                    }

                });
            });
            this.echo(response);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after struggling finding a way to solve this I finally did, I just put the ajax call inside a try catch and found that the error was that it wasn't reading the eurl variable (I declared it outside the evaluate). I put it inside and it worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to test this with the code you provided, but it looks as though you just aren't returning anything back from the `evaluate()`.

```js
return __utils__.sendAJAX(url, 'POST', params);
```

You would probably also need to call CasperJS with the following:

```js
casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true /path/to/script.js
```

Comment: It isn't working, I've tried with the native js xmlhttprequest and with \__utils__.sendAjax() casperJS method, I also tried putting the ajax inside a var so the value I return from the ajax request is the value of that var, and then I return it. What bugs me is that it works if I do it from the firebug console :/

Comment: sendAJAX() isn't working, it returns null, I've tried sending params as a JSON object and as a encoded string, none works

Comment: Could you try adding `this.then` around `this.echo(response);`?

Comment: I did it still, still doesn't work, there's something going wrong but I can't figure out what is it.